# R - Fixed length of vector while using lag function

Tags: r, csv, lag

I have a csv file(just call its name as 'csv') and want to use a lag function. Below is my code. (ColA and ColB are the name of columns of csv)

```
X <- subset(csv, ColA == 1)
Y <- c(NA, lag(X$ColB, 1))
```

Let's say there are 10 rows which satisfy ColA == 1. The problem is that I just want to have a vector of which length is 10 but after the lag function, its output shows a vector of which length is 11. How to fix it?

Comment: You don't need the **c(NA,**. You can just use _lag_

Comment: @akash87 I want to make the first element as NA, but if I just use lag, it shows some different result.

Comment: What lag function are you using (from which package)? There are multiple functions with this name.

Comment: @docendodiscimus stats package. Btw, I didn't know about that.

Comment: You can also use lagpad

Comment: @EdwardM. dplyr::lag() also works

Comment: @akash87 Thanks!

Comment: @Vlo Thanks too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `lagpad` function in the `ecm` package. This will leave off the last element of the vector to retain the same length.

```
library(ecm)
X <- 1:10
Y <- lagpad(X)
Y
[1] NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```